# esc_js() breaks unicode sequences by removing the slash '\' character

Tags: javascript, encoding, escaping

I've noticed that `esc_js()` is breaking unicode encoded characters by removing the '\' (slash) character. For example:

```
 esc_js('\u041f')
```

returns:

```
 'u041f'
```

I can potentially use REGEX to identify the unicode pattern characters and duplicate the slash, but I'm hoping there's alternative WP method that isn't breaking unicodes.